# urllib download excel file from php link

Tags: python, excel, python-2.7, urllib

I am trying to download a list of xls files from a url using [urllib.urlretrieve](https://docs.python.org/2/library/urllib.html) (python 2.7). I am able to get the file, however there is a `<script>` tag at the top of the file making it unreadable in excel.

here is what I have:

```
import urllib

files= ['a','b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f']

url = 'http://www.thewebsite.com/data/dl_xls.php?bid='

for f in files:
    urllib.urlretrieve(url + f, f + '.xls')
```

This downloads an xls file with the following at the top:
`<script>parent.parent.location.href = '../../../../a';</script>` which make it unreadable in excel.

If I remove that script tag from the xls, the file opens correctly in excel.

EDIT - Here is my solution from pypypy:

```
import urllib

files= ['a','b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f']

url = 'http://www.thewebsite.com/data/dl_xls.php?bid='

for f in files:
    input_xls =  f + '_in.xls'
    urllib.urlretrieve(url + f, input_xls)
    output = open(f + '_out.xls', "wb")
    with open(input_xls, "rb") as i:
        output.write(re.sub('<script>.*</script>', "", i.read(), re.I))
        i.close()
        output.close()
```

Comment: Are you sure that e.g. `http://www.thewebsite.com/data/dl_xls.php?bid=a` works?

Comment: I am able to get the file in a browser using that url, ONLY after i log in to the site. If I am not logged in, there is a script tag at the top of the xls. Once I remove the script tag, the file works fine.

Comment: You can perhaps use beautifulsoup to parse the content before outputting and say something like `soup.find('script').extract()` and then save the actual excel file

Comment: Thanks I though about using extract with bs, just wanted to make sure I wasn't missing anything with `urllib.urlretrieve`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try building a Regex to match the script tag and remove it i.e

```
import re
re.sub('<script>.*</script>', "", content, re.I)
```

This will substitute any script tags in the content for "".

Comment: I also recommend that you use the requests library its much simpler that urllib

Comment: thanks this worked, I ended up using urllib though. I'll update my original question with the solution.